# Creating a Signature Field in PDF Documents

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, signature, pdfmake, node-pdfkit

I have to create a PDF File where I use PDFmake to achieve this. But PDFmake does not has the feature to add a signature field into the document.

So I opened a sample PDF with a signature field and copied the object which contained the name of the signature field:

```
2 0 obj
<</F 4/Type/Annot/Subtype/Widget/Rect[294 465 470 420]/FT/Sig/DA(/Helv 0 Tf 0 g)/T(Signature2)/P 2 0 R>>
endobj
```

When I paste it into the new Document, it will show the Rect but as soon as I click on it, an error appears "The document can not be signed." (rough translation) while a click on the signature box in the sample PDF file triggers the sign process.

Now, my question is, what am I missing in the new Document?

Answer (score 0):

```
2 0 obj
<</F 4/Type/Annot/Subtype/Widget/Rect[294 465 470 420]/FT/Sig/DA(/Helv 0 Tf 0 g)/T(Signature2)/P 2 0 R>>
endobj
```

The last entry `/P 2 0 R` is not appropriate: The value of **P** shall be *an indirect reference to the page object with which this annotation is associated.* But apparently the field object itself is object `2 0`, obviously *not* a page object.

Thus, change the **P** value to point to the page object in question. Or drop it altogether, for form field widget annotations it is optional.

Other details which you may or may not yet have considered:

- The field has no **Parent** entry. Thus, it is a root field. Consequentially it has to be added to the **Fields** array in the **AcroForm** dictionary.
- The field is merged with its widget annotation. As the widget annotation it shall be referenced from its page's **Annots** array.
- The field is named "Signature2". Thus, make sure there is no other form field in your PDF with that name.

---

You talk about copying and pasting PDF objects between documents. If you by chance mean copy&paste in text editors, be extremely careful! Make sure that your editor can cope with arbitrary file content (even non-text contents) and does not damage them. And definitely update the cross reference tables or streams to match the offset changes your editing has effected.

Comment: If the measures mentioned above don't help, please share a binary copy of your PDF for analysis.